# Is there any solution to change color of QTableWidget's heads and items separately?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Is there any solution to change the font color of QTableWidget's heads and items separately using Qt Designer? I want to make a complete design in Qt Designer without using code to set any styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to add this as a comment but unfortunately my reputation is too low.

This should be possible by using a Stylesheet in the property editor. I can't test it right now but I assume it should look like these:

```css
QTableWidget {
    color: red;
}
QHeaderView {
    color: blue;
}
```

Edit: I saw later that you asked without using code to set any styles. This is as far as I know not possible. But you can set the Style in property editor as I suggested, s.t. you can see the changes in the Qt Designer directly.

Comment: thank you! 
maybe you know where I can find a list of these classes? because it's absolutely not obvious

Comment: You can find a list here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html and some examples here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html.
There are some more pages in the Qt documentation, check the next and previous pages of the one I suggested above. The navigation is a bit awkward in the Qt documentation, but this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html could be a starting point for stylesheets in general.